# 'typename' and alias templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

The following code compiles [using both Clang and GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfa72bbc9fc0b209), even though `Foo_t<T>::Bar` doesn't have `typename` in front of it:

```
struct Foo {
    using Bar = int;
};

template<class...>
using Foo_t = Foo;

template<class T>
void f(){
    Foo_t<T>::Bar b; // No typename!
}

int main(){
    f<int>();
}
```

Should it compile?

Comment: Template aliases are immediately replaced at their point of use, so the code  is equivalent to `template <class T> void f() { Foo::Bar b; }`, and there is no dependent name.

Answer (score 16):

#### Introduction

`Foo_t<T>::Bar` might look like a dependent-name, but it isn't since the *template-arguments* passed to the *alias-declaration* are not used when determining what the *qualified-id* `Bar` is referring to.

The code is well-formed.

---

---

#### What does the Standard ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) say?

> *14.5.7/2* **Alias templates** `[temp.alias]`
>
> > When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type
> >     obtained by substitution of its *template-arguments* for the *template-parameters* in the *type-id* of the alias
> >     template.

> *A.6* **Declarations** `[gram.dcl]`
>
> ```
> alias-declaration:
>   using identifier attribute-specifier-seq_opt = type-id ;
> ```

---

---

#### What is the Standard *really* saying?

Since there are no *template-parameters* in the *type-id* of `Foo_t`, the *template alias-declaration* is always directly equivalent to `Foo`, no matter what *template-arguments* we pass to it.

```
template<class... Ts>
using Foo_t = Foo;
//            ^--- "Foo" = type-id
```

---

Replacing the usage of `Foo_t<T>` with the equivalence of the *template alias-declaration* leaves us with the following:

```
template<class T>
void f(){
    Foo::Bar b; // ok, nothing here depends on `T`
}
```

Comment: So [temp.dep.type]/p8 - "A type is dependent if it is ... a *simple-template-id* in which ... any of the template arguments is a dependent type..." applies only to the type after alias templates substitution?

Comment: @T.C. The *type-id*  in the alias-declaration is not a *simple-template-id*.

Comment: No, I'm saying `Foo_t<T>` is a *simple-template-id*, and one of its template arguments, i.e., `T`, is a dependent type.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp maybe, but it is *also* a *simple-template-id* in which one of the template arguments is a dependent type.  So by that clause it *is* a dependent type.  Under the alias templates clause, it is also equivalent to `Foo`.  `Foo` is clearly *not* a dependent type.  This, on its face, seems like a contradiction.  Is there a clear clause that states that this contradiction must be resolved in favor of it not being a dependent type?  Or what "equivalent" means?  Or is there some sub-clause within [temp.dep.type]/p8 that states "this does not apply here"?

Comment: @Yakk I'll reply and update the answer when I get back home; the relevant wording is in the Standard. (*written on my blackberry*)

Answer (score 9):

With some more digging, this is [CWG issue 1390](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1390).

The issue description is

> According to 14.6.2.1 [temp.dep.type] paragraph 8, a type is dependent
>   (among other things) if it is
>
> > a *simple-template-id* in which either the template name is a template
> >     parameter or any of the template arguments is a dependent type or an
> >     expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent
>
> This applies to alias template specializations, even if the resulting
>   type does not depend on the template argument:
>
> ```
> struct B { typedef int type; };
> template<typename> using foo = B;
> template<typename T> void f() {
>   foo<T>::type * x;  //error: typename required
> }
> ```
>
> Is a change to the rules for cases like this warranted?

And there's a note in that issue:

> **Notes from the October, 2012 meeting:**
>
> CWG agreed that no `typename` should be required in this case. In some
>   ways, an alias template specialization is like the current
>   instantiation and can be known at template definition time.

The issue is still in "drafting" status, but it looks like the compiler vendors are already implementing the intended resolution.

Comment: The mentioned compiler vendors have always implemented it the way described, from what I know their implementation does **not** reflect the contents of that *DR*. Honestly I find the *DR* a bit.. well, *"not very thought through"* - the Standard has the required wording to come to the conclusion in my post.